# Second derivative of mollification at local maximum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $u:[-1,1] \mapsto \mathbf{R}$ be a continuous function with a local maximum at 0. That is, there is a ball $B_\delta(0)$ with $u(x) \leq u(0)$ for all $x \in B_\delta(0)$. Let $\eta(x)$ be the standard mollifier defined by
$$ \eta(x) = \begin{cases} C \exp\left(\frac{1}{|x|^2-1}\right) &\text{if } |x|< 1\\ 0 &\text{if } |x| \geq 1,\end{cases} $$
where $C$ is chosen so that $\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} \eta = 1$. For $x \in (-1+\epsilon, 1 - \epsilon)$ define the mollified function $u_\epsilon$ by
$$ u_\epsilon(x) = \int_{B(0,\epsilon)} \epsilon^{-n}\eta\left(\frac{y}{\epsilon}\right)u(x-y) \ dy. $$

Is it true that
$$ \liminf_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} u_\epsilon ''(0) \leq 0. $$

This would be true if the mollified function also had a local maximum at 0 — however this is not necessarily the case. As some further intuition it should be true that the mollification has a local max near 0, and this local max approaches the origin as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. However without something resembling uniform convergence I've been unable to turn this into a solution.

Note also the lim inf can not be replaced by a limit as we can construct a function for  for which $ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} u_\epsilon ''(0)$ does not exist. The idea behind the construction is to take any positive function for which the limit of the mollifications don't exist at 0 then integrate twice. More precisely take $h \in L^\infty[0,1]$ with $h \geq 0$ for which $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} h_{\epsilon}(0)$ does not exist. Set $g(x) = \int_0^x h(x)$ and $u(x) = \int_0^x g(x)$. Note $u(0)=0$ and $u \leq 0$. Then $h$ bounded implies $u,g$ are Lipschitz, and differentiable a.e with $u′=g$ and $g′=h$. Since the derivative of the mollification is the mollification of the derivative we have $(f_\epsilon)'' = u_\epsilon$ which we recall was chosen to not have a limit at 0.

Comment: If $u$ is twice differentiable at $x=0$, then the change of variables $y=\epsilon\xi$ shows that $u''_\epsilon(0)=\int_{B(0,1}\eta(\xi)u''(-\epsilon\xi)d\xi$, and Taylor's formula yields $u''_\epsilon(0)=u''(0)+o_{\epsilon\to0}(1)$ (using the normalization of $\eta$), which is thus negative if $|\epsilon|\ll1$. BUT, if $u$ is only continuous, then $u''_\epsilon(0)=\epsilon^{-2}u(0)\int_{B(0,1)}\eta''(\xi)d\xi+\epsilon^{-2}\int_{B(0,1)}\eta''(\xi)(u(-\epsilon\xi)-u(0))d\xi$ and I do not think that it has in general a limit as $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I think you're right about the limit sometimes not existing. I edited the question to just ask about the lim inf.

Comment: Is the local maximum a strict one? In that case, I would guess that $u_\epsilon$ also has a local maximum at $0$ for small enough $\epsilon$, easily solving the problem. This might be true also in the non-strict case but it is probably going to be harder. Just thinking. PS: oh, reading again I see that you don't think this is a viable strategy, sorry then

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Giuseppe Negro. The local max is not necessarily strict. For a nonstrict local max we can consider, say, the function $u(x) = 0$ where $x \leq 0$ and $-x$ where $x > 0$ to see that the point 0 is no longer a local max of the mollified function.

Comment: @CaleRankin: you wrote in the edit history that "The result is not true with a limit". Would you like to edit the question and explain this? Is it because the limit can blow up at $-\infty$, like in the example of your previous comment?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro 
This explanation might derail the question. Let me know if you think I should add it above, or provide more details. Take $h\in L^\infty[0,1], h\leq0$ for which $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}h_\epsilon(0)$ does not exist. Set $g(x):=\int_0^xh(x)$ and $u(x):=\int_0^xg(x)$. Note $u(0) = 0$ and $u \leq 0$. Then $h$ bounded yields $u,g$ Lipschitz, and differentiable a.e with $u'=g,g'=h$. Since the derivative of the mollification is the mollification of the derivative we have $(f_\epsilon)''=h_\epsilon$. Thanks for your interest in my question, and adding a bounty.

Comment: I am interested in this problem. From what I could understand, I guess that the result is not true for the $\limsup$. I didn't manage to write the conterexample explicitly, but one can consider a self-similar function, i.e. such that $u(x)=u(\alpha x)/\alpha$ for some constant $\alpha>0$ and for sufficiently small $x$. In that way, as soon as (and this is a big IF) you have an $\varepsilon$ for which $u_\varepsilon''(0)>0$, you have infinitely many, and for those $\varepsilon$ going to 0, $u_\varepsilon''(0)$ goes to infinity. It would actually be more natural  $u(x)=u(\alpha x)/\alpha^2$

Comment: This would be a possible strategy to also find a counterexample for the liminf, but it is clealry more complex. The benefit is that you just have to build u such that $u_\varepsilon''(0)>0$ for all $\varepsilon\in[\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0/\alpha]$. My point is that, if $u(x)=u(\alpha x)/\alpha^2$ for small $x$, then $u_\epsilon''(0)$ is a periodic function of $-\log(\varepsilon)$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$. (I hope I am not messing with the constants). Here and in the previous comment I am assuming $u(0)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\alpha>1$

Comment: @LorenzoPompili: i find it hard to follow your reasoning. If you think you have an incomplete solution, please post it with more details. You can make it community wiki if you are unsure about it.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Ok, I will try to do it when I have some time. I think I can exhibit an interesting example where the limsup is strictly positive. Maybe from my example we could come up with something analogous but with positive liminf working a bit more (thus proving that the estimate is false).

Comment: @CaleRankin Is there a reason you expect this to be/not be the case? Your comment on the counterexample also counts as context, so I request you to add it to the question post at the end. It will be useful and I didn't see it, so I'd like others to see it as well!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I expect it to be the case, but don't have a strong argument as to why. My intuition is whilst the local maximum does not imply the mollification also has a local maximum, it should imply the mollified function does have a local maximum nearby. Then, vaguely, a double limit argument should give the desired result. However without any uniform convergence I was not able to carry out this double limit argument.

Comment: @CaleRankin I think this is good intuition. I was thinking about "why " you would ask this question and this thought did hit me! I think I expected failure as well, but only from a very pathological example like the one below. Can I request you to add your comment to the post, as motivation for this question? Thanks once again, it was a great question.

Answer (score 3):

So, this is an **incomplete solution** that hopefully can give some ideas. The spirit here is to **find a counterexample** to the main statement. What I have managed to do is to find a $u$ for which $\limsup_{\epsilon\to 0^+}u_\epsilon''(0)>0$, and I hope to manage to obtain the same thing for the $\liminf$ with a similar construction. The idea is to build $u$ such that $u_\epsilon''(0)$ oscillates with some sort of periodicity as
$\epsilon\to 0^+$.
I don't know if the statement is true or not though, but also trying to exhibit counterexamples could give ideas for proving that a statement is true.

I hope it is not a problem, but I feel more comfortable changing the domain of $u$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and assuming
$$u:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}\;\;\text{continuous},\qquad u(0)=0\,,\qquad u(x)\leq 0\quad\forall x\in \mathbb{R}.\qquad \text{(HP)}$$
I think we agree that this is equivalent to the original problem.

---

**Definition of self-similar function**

Let's consider a function $u$ with the hypotheses (HP) and such that $\exists\, \delta>0,\alpha>1$ such that
$$u(x)=u(\alpha x)/\alpha^2\qquad\forall x\in[-\delta,\delta].$$

I will call it *self-similar function*, as it also holds from that that
$$u(x)=u(\alpha^n x)/\alpha^{2n}\qquad\forall x\in[-\delta/\alpha^{n-1},\delta/\alpha^{n-1}].$$

Let's compute $u_\epsilon''(0)$ assuming $\epsilon\leq\delta$:
$$u_\epsilon''(0) = \int_{B(0,\epsilon)} \epsilon^{-3}\eta''\left(\frac{y}{\epsilon}\right)u(y) \ dy=\int_{B(0,\epsilon)} \epsilon^{-3}\eta''\left(\frac{y}{\epsilon}\right)u(\alpha y)/\alpha^2 \ dy=$$
$$=\int_{B(0,\alpha\epsilon)} \epsilon^{-3}\eta''\left(\frac{z}{\alpha\epsilon}\right)u(z)/\alpha^3 \ dz=u_{\alpha\epsilon}''(0) $$

Let's make the change of variable $s:=-\ln(\epsilon)$, i.e. $\epsilon=\exp(-s)$. The above computation means that the function
$$ f_u(s):= u''_{\exp(-s)}(0) $$
is periodic with period $\ln \alpha$ in the interval $s\in[-\ln\delta,+\infty)$, as we have
$$ u''_{\exp(-s)}(0)=u''_{\alpha\exp(-s)}(0)=u''_{\exp(+\ln(\alpha)-s)}(0)\qquad\forall s\geq-\ln\delta \iff \epsilon\leq\delta.$$

---

**Why a self-similar function can be useful to prove or disprove the statement**

So, since $\epsilon\to 0^+$ is the same thing of $s\to+\infty$, we are interested in the behaviour of $f_u(s)$ for large $s$. In particular, our problem is equivalent to prove that for all $u$ that satisfy the hypotheses (HP), it holds
$$ \liminf_{s\to+\infty}f_u(s)\leq 0$$

For *self-similar* functions $u$, we have proved that $f_u(s)$ is periodic for $s$ large enough. If we could exhibit a *self-similar function* $u$ such that $f(s)\geq c>0$ for one whole period of $f$, i.e. for $s\in[s_0,s_0+\ln\alpha]$ where $s_0\geq-\ln\delta$ and for some $c>0$, we would find a counterexample and the claim is false.

---

**A partial result, and an example of construction of a self-similar function**

At the moment, it seems a bit complicated to find such $u$ if it exists, but I can actually exhibit an example of $u$ such that
$$ \limsup_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} u_\epsilon ''(0) > 0, $$
that is,
$$ \limsup_{s\to+\infty}f_u(s)> 0.$$
Since $f_u$ is periodic for $s\geq-\ln \delta$, it just suffices to find $s_0\geq-\ln \delta$ such that $f_u(s_0)>0$.

My example is that of a function that is only continuous in $0$ for the sake of simplicity and has some jumps, but with some more calculations, one could build a function with the same properties that is also continuous (for example, regularizing $\phi$ before the following construction).

Let's thus consider
$$ \phi(x):= -\chi_{[-1,-\gamma]}(x)-\chi_{[\gamma,1]}(x),$$
where $\chi_I$ is the characteristic function of the interval $I$ and $0<\gamma<1$ is a small constant to be chosen later. Then let's define $u$ as follows:
$$ u(x)=\sum_{n=-2}^\infty \phi(\alpha^nx)/\alpha^{2n},$$
where $1<\alpha$ is to be chosen later, and we assume $\gamma^{-1}<\alpha$ so that the characteristic functions don't overlap.

You can check that $u$ is well-defined, is continuous in $x=0$, it is uniformly bounded by $0$ from above and it's *self-similar* with constants $\delta=\alpha$, and $\alpha$ is the same $\alpha$ in the definition of self-similarity. Rewriting the conditions that I have written in the beginning of this section, it's just necessary to prove
$$ \exists \;0<\epsilon<\alpha\quad\text{such that } u_\epsilon ''(0) > 0.$$

This is true if we choose:
(1) $\epsilon=2$
(2) $0<\gamma<1$
(3) $\alpha>4/\gamma$

Unfortunately, this is just a boring matter of estimating $u_\epsilon''(0)$, as the explicit computation would be very long. The idea is that choosing $\epsilon=2$ (that is, big but not too big), the term of the series for $n=0$ has positive second derivative in $x=0$ when regularized with parameter $\epsilon$, because of the facts that $-\eta$ has positive second derivative near $x=0$ and $\phi$ is negative. The terms with $n\geq 1$ have a positive contribution for the same reason. The contribution of the terms for $n=-1,-2$ is $0$ because $\alpha$ is taken very large, and the support of their regularization does not touch $x=0$.

---

**So...**

So, the question that I have now is: does this construction work to prove the same result for the $\liminf$? We still have some freedom in choosing $\gamma$, which I have basically not used, but it seems more difficult... I will try to think about it. I hope that someone has some clever idea for a simpler proof :)

Comment: I just want to remark that one can also do the same thing asking $u(x)=u(\alpha x)/\alpha^\beta\qquad\forall x\in[-\delta,\delta]$ for any $0<\beta\leq 2$, and $f_u(s)$ would be a periodic function multiplied by some increasing exponential function of $s$, but I think things don't change so much changing $\beta$

Comment: I awarded the bounty. This is a serious effort. I can only recommend being more concise, but if this is your style, then go for it and ignore my recommendations.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thank you for it and your advice. I am still finding my style, so I am open to suggestions :) I am still struggling with the full question, it’s a pity to leave it as it is

Comment: @LorenzoPompili this is an interesting answer and I appreciate your response. It is still worthwhile to know the result is false for a lim sup. Though I am in the same boat as you --- no real luck at turning this into a counter example for the lim inf.

Comment: +1 to both question and answer, this one has been great fun to think about.

Comment: Thank you, Cale. Yes, I still don't see how this can be turned into a counterexample for the liminf. What I hope is that maybe at some point I realize that it is not possible to obtain a couterex. with this kind of functions, and this provides an idea on why the result is true. As a second thought, I was trying to integrate $f_u(s)$ multiplied by some power weight to see if the integral is finite and if this gives some conditions, but still no luck

Comment: This last thing as it is doesn't even make sense if $f_u$ is periodic. I was just wandering "could it be this useful to integrate in ds?"